# Use of which.min and coefficients from function

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
x<-c(1,1,3,8,5,2,4,3,1,1,0,5,1,1,3,4,6,7,8,9,4,2,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,1,2,3,5,7,9)
```

I use an incrementally (-1) lagged version of x in the following function model to test which lag provides a lower AIC result in the following function. The `Lag()` function is from package **quantmod*.

```
library("quantmod")
a1 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,1))
a2 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,2)) 
a3 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,3)) 
a4 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,4)) 
a5 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,5)) 
a6 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,6)) 
a7 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,7)) 
a8 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,8)) 
a9 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,9)) 
a10 <- glm(x[1:length(x)] ~ Lag(x,10))
```

On another hand I would like to extract the AIC coefficient in `a1[[11]]`... and find the smallest AIC from `a1` to `a10`. I do it as follows but I get the following error.

```
which.min(a1[[11]],a2[[11]],a3[[11]],a4[[11]],a5[[11]],a6[[11]],a7[[11]],a8[[11]],
a9[[11]],a10[[11]])
Error en which.min(a11[[11]], a22[[11]], a33[[11]], a44[[11]], a55[[11]],  : 
unused arguments (a22[[11]], a33[[11]], a44[[11]], a55[[11]], a66[[11]], a77[[11]],   
a88[[11]], a99[[11]], a1010[[11]])
```

Would you happen how can I extract and if possible compute the `which.min` at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you took a more R-ish approach to doing this, for example with your data

```
x <- c(1,1,3,8,5,2,4,3,1,1,0,5,1,1,3,4,6,7,8,9,4,2,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,1,2,3,5,7,9)
```

you can fit the models in a single call:

```
mods <- lapply(seq_len(10), function(i, x) {glm(x ~ Lag(x, i))}, x = x)
```

which conveniently arranges the models in a list for you, which you can iterate over.

Second tip is to use extractor functions. You shouldn't need to know where to look for the AIC, just use the `AIC()` generic. Combine this with `sapply()` and we get a vector of AIC values for the fitted models:

```
sapply(mods, AIC)

R> sapply(mods, AIC)
 [1] 156.8 163.0 158.0 150.4 147.1 144.2 141.1 134.5 131.6 126.7
```

And as this is a *vector* of values we can now use `which.min()`:

```
which.min(sapply(mods, AIC))

R> which.min(sapply(mods, AIC))
[1] 10
```

The reason your call failed is that you passed 10 vectors (each of length 1) to the `which.min()` function where it was expecting a single vector from which to select the minimum. You could have used `c()` to concatenate them all together, but starting out with a better approach to fitting and storing the models, R will do that for you if you invoke the right tools.

Finally, do be careful with `which.min()`; if two or more elements take the minimum value, `which.min()` returns the first of these minimums. To be defensive, you can do:

```
vals <- sapply(mods, AIC)
which(vals == min(vals))

R> vals <- sapply(mods, AIC)
R> which(vals == min(vals))
[1] 10
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a sound approach *statistically*, so *Caveat emptor*!

Answer (score 0):

```
b<-c(a1[[11]],a2[[11]],a3[[11]],a4[[11]],a5[[11]],a6[[11]],a7[[11]], a8[[11]],   
a9[[11]],a10[[11]])
which(b == min(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pulls the aic number for incrementally lagged values of your vector, but are you sure what you are doing makes sense?  I'm not familiar with the actual functions you are using, but it is very suspicious that your min aic number is basically for the largest offset you try (to actually get your answer, you would do `which.min` on the result of the below):

```
sapply(
  1:(length(x) - 2L), 
  function(y) glm(formula=x ~ Lag(x, y))$aic
)
# [1] 156.758055 162.994470 158.022507 150.382848 147.112939 144.217309 141.115049 134.461170
# [9] 131.556481 126.682320 119.779543 116.410508 110.665231 104.261180  97.765081  94.042869
# [17]  92.527751  86.122867  81.247572  75.982221  72.414620  67.337715  61.407616  57.108097
# [25]  52.830527  41.671213  41.808836  40.550707  34.626992  24.341564  17.195847  13.297236
# [33]   9.675754
```